# Messages are deleted automatically

Tags: ms-office, message, microsoft-teams

I noticed that the root of a Teams Conversation thread gets "deleted" after a few hours. At least it seems like it is deleted. In fact all the replies can still be seen. The message that started the thread does not get deleted it just shifts into the replies. I have no explanation for this. I did not delete the message and I'm the only one on this Teams Channel.

Those mesages are created via POST where I send a json to

```
https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/v3/conversations/12:34abc5de67f8912gh345i67j890klmo1@thread.skype;messageid=234567891234
```

The number after `messageid=` is something I generate with

```
    public string GenerateNum()
    {
        var random = new System.Random();
        string msgId = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            msgId += random.Next(10);
        }
        return msgId;
    }
```

I assume that is the problem why my messages get kinda "deleteded".

Does anyone know why my messages get deleted and how I could fix it?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the scenario? Are you trying to [post messages in a channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)?

Comment: Hi, I'm posting messages to a channel already. One thing I noticed now though is that in the microsoft docs they POST to "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages" while I POST to "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/v3/conversation/{conversationID}/activities"

Comment: here is a screenshot of how it looks like in teams: https://imgur.com/SWX1INg

Comment: Could you please check these [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#create-conversation) and see if you are missing out something?